# Why does the following part crash my browser?

Tags: javascript, html, debugging

I just wanted to add the following part to my code. When I do this, I get no more output in the console and the browser crashes every time. If I comment out the part, everything works fine again. I have already tested everything (shortened loop runs, smaller data set, ..) but nothing helps.
Does somebody has any idea?

```
var index_avg_temp_array = []; // array which saves the temperature of each Cluster
index_avg_temp_array.push([]); // creates 2d array
for (id = 0; id < cluster_points; id++) {
  // id = index of the cluster

  var t_array = []; // create array / set array to 'empty'
  var amount = 0;
  var check = 0;

  // takes the id and check if day_array[].index === id
  for (day = 0; day < days_of_year; day++) {
    // 365/366 runs, day_array has 1 entry for each day

    if (day_array[day].index === id) {
      for (hour = 0; hour < 24; hour++) {
        // if true - save the hourly temperatures in hour_array

        var row = day * 24 + hour;
        var t_temp = hour_array[row].temp; // temperature of each hour
        t_array.push(t_temp);
      }
      check = 1; // if index was found for at least 1 time
      amount = amount + 1;
    }
  }
  if (check === 1) {
    // check if the index was found for at least 1 time
    for (hour = 0; hour < 24; hour++) {
      var avg = 0;
      for (counter = 0; counter < t_array.length; counter + 24) {
        var row = hour * 24 + counter;
        avg = avg + t_array[row]; // sum up each hour
      }

      var avg_hours = avg / amount; // calculate the avg of the hour
      index_avg_temp_array[id].push(avg_hours); // save the avg temperatures of each hour for each cluster point
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share with us the value of `cluster_points`, `days_of_year`, variables?

Comment: Are you sure that's not supposed to be `id < cluster_points.length` or similar? IOW, is it possible that the loop never terminates?

Comment: While you're waiting for help you should go through and make sure that **all** of your variables are properly declared.

Comment: @benmotyka cluster_points = 6; days_of_year is 365 or 366

Comment: @AKX cluster_points isnt an array. It's just a variable that indicates the number of clusters you want.

Comment: @MaxWeller you are not changing the value of `cluster_points` on which the loop relies.

Comment: @ABDULLOKHMUKHAMMADJONOV The idea behind this is that I have 6 cluster points. For each point I would like to have the associated hourly average temperatures. So I go through the loop from 0 to 5 (6 passes for cluster point 1 to 6). So I don't have to change the value of `cluster_points`

Comment: @MaxWeller You are entering an infinite loop as `day < days_of_year` condition is never met.

Comment: counter never gets updated and probably results in an infinte loop. Change `counter + 24` to `counter += 24` in that last for loop.

Comment: @ABDULLOKHMUKHAMMADJONOV `for (day = 0; day < days_of_year; day++)`  This loop just counts up from 0 to 365 because  `days_of_year` is set to 366. Where is there an infinite loop? Can you explain it in more detail?

Comment: @phuzi oh thats a good idea. i'll try it!!

Comment: @phuzi Perfect! No more crashes! Thank you very much! But now there is an error message (Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')) in line `index_avg_temp_array[id].push(avg_hours);` . So I still have a lot to do. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (counter = 0; counter < t_array.length; counter + 24) {
```

This results in an infinte loop because `counter` never gets updated. `counter + 24` should be `counter += 24`:

```
for (counter = 0; counter < t_array.length; counter += 24) {
```